# django search multiple tables while typing

Tags: django, search, while-loop, typing, typeahead

I want to be able to type my search query into an input field and while typing, get a drop-down with suggestions for matched objects in my Django database.

The search should match only some specific tables and only search specific columns, however, the returned object must have a full row of content.

The only thing I've got at the moment is JQuery Chosen, which does most of what i want.

1. It gives suggestions in a drop-down
2. It is possibly to search for a name and in return get an ID
3. Can search any list of data

My trouble with Chosen is that it returns only one value, so if I use it to search IDs from multiple tables, it might return identical data.

What I am considering is to do some magic with Json and Ajax, however, those two are very new acquaintances of mine, so I'd like to know, if there is a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer, No.

You should work this out with Ajax and JSON like you suggested yourself.

**Hint**, the terminology is called *`typeahead`*.

Also it sounds like you are trying to implement a basic search using the Django ORM.
Although practice is a good teacher, you ought to look into libraries like [django-haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/), possibly with a search engine that is easy to set up like [Whoosh](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Whoosh/). This will allow you to setup different models for searching easily.

Haystack is well documented so it should be understandable. Your question is rather broad so I would try to set things up and ask questions on a more detailed level accordingly.

Comment: Does haystack support typeahead though? From skimming the promotion it looked like it was based around form posts